# Chrome not showing console messages via console.log

Tags: google-chrome, console.log

This is a completely new one on me:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log("loaded");
    alert("LOADED");
});
```

The alert pops. The console is empty completely. Did I accidentally trip some Chrome setting (71.0.3578.98) or did Chrome somehow break logging with an update? I thought my content load was just off with some sort of async initially, but adding the alert the code is **definitely** being fired.

[image]

(I see now there is a tiny gray message that says "2 hidden" but clicking it does nothing. Checking/unchecking the above checkboxes seems to have no effect.

**More shenanigans**

Literally running a `console.log()` in the console itself shows the expected undefined return in the console, but not the console log itself.

[image]

**Other browsers**

IE 11 shows both the alert and the console log as expected.

Comment: Is your 'Info' level checked in levels drop-down? (It's placed to the right from filter input in console tab)

Comment: @TarasPolovyi yup. Added snip

Comment: Hmm, you have "GMT" string in your filter input, so it filters all the console output. It may be the case.

Comment: @TarasPolovyi literally JUST realized that myself. ID10T error.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is... I'm an idiot.

Upon closer inspection, I had a search term in the "Filter" bar at the top. See the image in the OP. Leaving this here as a reminder, if it's broken it's probably a PEBKAC issue.